# Unitarily invariant functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F$  be a continuous function on the space of $N\times N$ hermitian matrices  $\mathcal{H}_N$ taking values in $\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $F(UMU^*)=F(M)$ for all $M\in \mathcal{H}_N$ and $U\in U(N)$, where the later stands for the unitary group of $\mathbb{C}^N$.

The first examples coming in mind are the Trace, and the Determinant. Do you know is there exists a way to express $F$ in terms of these two functions ? Or maybe under stronger conditions than continuity for $F$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every symmetric function of the eigenvalues has this property. The [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in the eigenvalues (the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial) freely generate the ring of symmetric polynomials, and these are dense in the space of functions you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, I was looking for an answer like that. But how can you write the elementary symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues in terms of Trace and Det ? (except the first and last one of course), maybe using minors ?

Comment: Something else, my function can be defined on an unbounded set, right ? I thus don't understand the density argument.

Comment: @Student: you can't. Their values aren't determined by the values of the trace and determinant. I don't understand the second question.

Comment: But you can write the elementary symmetric polynomial as a trace of an appropriate exterior power of the matrix (and perhaps also using a sum of determinants using Cauchy-Binet type of stuff)